# Flume twitter - Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives

Tags: twitter-oauth, twitter4j, flume, flume-twitter

I am trying to ingest some twitter data though apache flume and so, sink to kafka. This is only for study purpose and I am stuck in this erro:

```
root@engsrv:/de/apache-flume-1.10.0-bin/bin# ./flume-ng agent --conf-file /de/apache-flume-1.10.0-bin/conf/flume-twitter --name agent
Warning: No configuration directory set! Use --conf <dir> to override.
Info: Including Hive libraries found via () for Hive access
+ exec /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-18/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/de/apache-flume-1.10.0-bin/lib/*:/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application --conf-file /de/apache-flume-1.10.0-bin/conf/flume-twitter --name agent
20:54:07.029 [Twitter Stream consumer /  [1][Establishing connection]] ERROR org.apache.flume.source.twitter.TwitterSource - Exception while streaming tweets
twitter4j.TwitterException: 403:The request is understood, but it has been refused. An accompanying error message will explain why. This code is used when requests are being denied due to update limits (https://support.twitter.com/articles/15364-about-twitter-limits-update-api-dm-and-following).
<html>\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>\n<title>Error 403
Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives
</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>HTTP ERROR: 403</h2>
<p>Problem accessing '/1.1/statuses/sample.json?stall_warnings=true'. Reason:
<pre>
Please use V2 filtered and sample volume stream as alternatives
</pre>
</body>
</html>

        at twitter4j.HttpClientImpl.handleRequest(HttpClientImpl.java:170) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
        at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.request(HttpClientBase.java:57) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
        at twitter4j.HttpClientBase.get(HttpClientBase.java:75) ~[twitter4j-core-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
        at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl.getSampleStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:201) ~[twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
        at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$4.getStream(TwitterStreamImpl.java:170) ~[twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
        at twitter4j.TwitterStreamImpl$TwitterStreamConsumer.run(TwitterStreamImpl.java:570) [twitter4j-stream-4.0.7.jar:4.0.7]
```

I guess I need to enable this authentication option on twitter developer page:

[image]

But what should I enter here?

[image]

The *i* says

> Callback URLs are destinations that OAuth is allowed to redirect after
> the authentication process. It is important to identify your callback
> URLs so that OAuth recognizes the specified URLs as valid.

What should be uri in a case of local machine test?

Comment: are you still getting the error or did you fixed it? If you have fixed it let me know how did you do? Even I am getting the same error

Answer (score -1):

you can enter https://www.gmail.com for both or for local machine just give http://127.0.0.1

Comment: Gmail isn't an oauth2 server, and it won't accept localhost because that'll cause the server to callback to itself, not your own computer